# Nil object after new object validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm trying to incorporate validation into some of my models, but when doing that, if something doesn't validate, I get the error messages "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!", "You might have expected an instance of Array." and "The error occurred while evaluating nil.map". Taking a look at [my code](https://github.com/Chiggins/RedditClone/blob/446f430604442f9db4ba29468c73ab718af0aab0/app/models/subreddit.rb), I add in the lines "validates_uniqueness_of :name" and "validates_format_of :name, :with => /^[A-Za-z\d_]+$/" right after line 3, and whenever I make a submission that would not validate, I get the errors.

Application trace:

```
    app/views/subreddits/new.html.haml:13:in `block in _app_views_subreddits_new_html_haml___455774545377436650_34289940'
app/views/subreddits/new.html.haml:4:in `_app_views_subreddits_new_html_haml___455774545377436650_34289940'
    app/controllers/subreddits_controller.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in create'
    app/controllers/subreddits_controller.rb:48:in `create
```

'

Comment: seems the problem lies in the view. What do you have line 13? I guess something looping for error messages?

Comment: @apneadiving - https://github.com/Chiggins/RedditClone/blob/master/app/views/subreddits/new.html.haml ... line 13 contains: = select("subreddit", "link_type", @link_types)

Comment: ok so `@link_types` is nil. How do you set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, on the `create` action of the controller, you need to set `@link_types` so that when you fail to save, you can render the `new` template properly. You probably should set the `@link_types` value as a constant or do it in a helper to make it DRYer.

```
def create
  params[:subreddit][:created_by_id] = session[:user_id]
  @subreddit = Subreddit.new(params[:subreddit])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @subreddit.save
      format.html { redirect_to @subreddit, notice: 'Subreddit was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @subreddit, status: :created, location: @subreddit }
    else
      format.html do
        @link_types = {"link" => "link", "text" => "text", "both" => "both"}
        render action: "new"
      end
      format.json { render json: @subreddit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you're talking about. Though, what do you mean by "DRYer"?

Comment: @Chiggins DRY is an acronym for Don't Repeat Yourself. Check out the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself.